# XSLT to remove elements implicitly

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to create a stylesheet to copy `<body>` element to output and drop all other elements implicitly.

Source:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <info>trial</info>
    <style>unknown</style>
    <body>
        <section>
            <p>para 1</p>
            <p>para 2</p>
        </section>
    </body>
</document>
```

Desired output:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <body>
        <section>
            <p>para 1</p>
            <p>para 2</p>
        </section>
    </body>
</document>
```

XSLT:

```
<!-- language: lang-xsl -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>       

    <xsl:template match="node()[not(descendant-or-self::body)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output of the aforementioned XSLT:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <body/>
</document>
```

P.s. I am a newbie to XSLT. If you could explain your solution and point me to a suitable resource to learn xpath and xslt 1.0, it will be a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `section` does not have a `body` descendant, so it is matches your template and is removed. You probably meant to write `[not(ancestor-or-self::body)]` - but that would also include the root `document`, so the result would be empty. Why not do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="document">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="body"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or even simpler:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/document">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="body"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k. Do you mean `descendant-or-self::body` looks through all elements of the input XML to see if it is a body element or if it has a  descendant body element?

Comment: `descendant-or-self::body` looks for an element named `body` on the `descendant or-self` axis. *"The descendant-or-self axis contains the context node and the descendants of the context node"* [1](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#axes). The context node for a predicate expression is the node being matched [2](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#predicates).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it.
I put some hints/explanations in comment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="document">
      <xsl:copy> <!-- copy the current node (not its content) -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="body"/> <!-- Apply templates to selected node -->
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Identity template. Ref : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzknsS